# Find all units and zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring  $\mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_6$. Find all units and zero divisors. There are only $4$ units:

$(1,1)(1,1)= (1,1)$

$(1,5)(1,5)=(1,1)$

$(2,1)(2,1)=(1,1)$

$(2,5)(2,5)=(1,1)$.

Comment: Hi: problem statements are helpful for explaining context, but it's customary to *ask a question* in your post. With my (very poor) psychic powers I'm guessing you are asking how to find the zero divisors. But that seems rather surprising considering that you're handling the units so well. Did you try anything with the things that aren't units?!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$(0,?)(?,0)=(0,0)$

$2\cdot3=0$ in $\Bbb Z_6$.

To make sure you didn't miss any, count up how many elements you discovered this way and compare it with how big you expect the ring to be.